Comparing ssGSEA Scores across different signatures within the same sample
I have a dataset consisting of hundreds of RNA-seq samples. I have performed ssGSEA using a curated set of signatures on these samples with the default parameters, including the final normalization step as described by Barbie et al., 2009.
From my understanding, it is possible to compare ssGSEA scores of the same signature across different samples. However, I am uncertain whether it is valid to compare ssGSEA scores across different signatures within the same sample. Specifically, can I say that signature X has a higher score than signature Y in a given sample?
I suspect that the final normalization step might prevent such comparisons. Would skipping the normalization step make this comparison meaningful?
I have searched through various forums but haven’t found a clear answer. Any insights or references would be greatly appreciated!
